# ASP.NET Core API - View is not displayed after redirect from Api Controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I am having some troubles while redirecting from Api Controller to Controller. I can see in postman response, that correct View is returned.

```
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("/someApiAction/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SomeApiAction(string id)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Action", "Other", new { id = id});
    }
}
```

Other Controller:

```
public class OtherController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Action(string id)
    {   
        var model = new Model();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Code reaches *return View(model)* but it's not displayed.

Can anybody please help on this one?

Comment: The controller name in redirect should be `Other`, not `Controller`.

Comment: Corrected. Anyway, that was not the case.

Comment: @Xardas by correct view you mean the source content (ie html) or the displayed URL?

Comment: Also is the shown code accurate? You have async Actions with no awaits.

Comment: We would need to see more information to really help. Do you actually have a view at "Views/Other/Action.cshtml"?

Comment: Yes, I have this View. Postman returns HTML of this View, but its not displayed on the screen.

Comment: How did you request web api method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are requesting the web api controller from `PostMan` instead of `Html` page. For check the page from `Postman`, you need to copy the content out and view it from browser by view html online site.

For `Postman`, it will not be able to open web browser from the response.

Try to check the html by request the api controller like code below:

```
<form asp-controller="UserApi" asp-action="SomeApiAction" asp-route-id="2" formmethod="post">
    <button type="submit">Request Api</button>
</form>
```